# Python: bytearray to ctypes array

Tags: python, arrays, ctypes

I am trying to write `bytearray` into the ctypes `c_uint8` buffer of a ctypes structure

```
class RpRes(LittleEndianStructure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
        ("count", c_uint16),
        ("buf", c_uint8 * 512)
    ]

def read_func(req):
    res = RpRes()
    buf = os.read(req.fd, req.count)
    res.buf.from_buffer(buf)
    res.count = len(buf)
    return res
```

`res.buf.from_buffer(buf)`
gives the below error:

> AttributeError: 'c_ubyte_Array_512' object has no attribute
> 'from_buffer'

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
def read_func(req):
    res = RpRes()
    buf = os.read(req.fd, req.count)
    res.buf = (c_uint8 * sizeof(res.buf))(*buf)
    res.count = len(buf)
    return res
```